# Javascript or jQuery to accept numbers less than 100 for text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project I have a text field where I need to accept values less than or equal to 100. In that text field how can I achieve this through javascript or jquery. Somehow I have managed to accept only numbers in text box but how can i restrict it not accept numbers greater than 100.

Here is the code which I have tried to accept only numbers

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `<input type="number" max="100">`, Use simple HTML

Comment: @govindsinghnagarkoti, thats `perl` question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, you can use `number` type in HTML5 with the `max` attribute set to 100.

```
<input id="numberbox" type='number' max='100'>
```

This will allow your browser to detect when it's over `100` when submitted. However, it won't work on older browsers and some smartphones.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
<input type='text' maxlength='2' pattern='^[0-9]$'>
```

But I feel this option is overkill. But if you want to do it that way, that's up to you.

In jQuery, you can do this:

```js
$('#numberbox').keyup(function(){
  if ($(this).val() > 100){
    alert("No numbers above 100");
    $(this).val('100');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='numberbox'>
```

Please also validate back-end, someone with only just enough knowledge could easily bypass this.

Comment: is it `<input id="numberbox"` or `<input id-"numberbox"` ?

Comment: `id='numberbox'` - I just can't type. @CJRamki

Comment: type="number" is managed in different ways by each browser so the first option can be problematic if you're working with floats.

Comment: i think sign need to change in if condition. if ($(this).val() > 100)

Comment: Thanks, no idea how that managed to be in there for 3 years @SushilKumar

Answer (score 3):

Check this [`demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/ySt7S/10/)

Also you have to restrict the length of `text field`

Something like this

```
var fieldVal = document.getElementById('txtF').value;
//Suppose u want  number that is less than 100
if(fieldVal < 100){
    return true;
}
else
{
  //
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With jquery you can to something like this :

```
$('#my-field').blur(function() {
   if(parseInt($(this).val()) < 100) {
       $(this).val('');
   }
});
```

The blur event is thrown when user leave the field (field loose the focus). Then it chekcks if the value is less than 100 and empty it if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$('yourElem').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(this.value > 100){
       alert('You have entered more than 100 as input');
       return false;
    }
});
```

---

`maxlength` attribute can restrict the numbers more than 3 digits, so you can use this to restrict:

```
maxlength="3"
```

yet you need to do js validation as suggested above because user with `maxlength` still can enter more than 100 as asked.

Answer (score 2):

along with your code you can add one more line to  restrict text-field to accept less than 2 char....

```
    if (charCode.length > 2) {
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    var str = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    if (str>100)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

you can use fromCharCode it can return character

Answer (score 1):

please use max length

```
maxlength="2"
```

EX.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp">
  PIN: <input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="2" size="30"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnc(value, min, max) 
{
    if(parseInt(value) < 0 || isNaN(value)) 
        return 0; 
    else if(parseInt(value) > 100) 
        return "Number is greater than 100"; 
    else return value;
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="textWeight" id="txtWeight" maxlength="5" onkeyup="this.value = fnc(this.value, 0, 100)"/>
```